# PIC Write-Protect Behavior

Tags: pic, programming, microchip

When I write protect a PIC using the config bits, does it prevent ***all*** future programming or can I still reprogram the part if I erase it first?  I assume this behavior should be standard across all their products, but if it matters I'm using a PIC18 series micro.  The datasheet only tells me what I can set, not the actual effect of setting the config bits.

[image: Sample Config Register]

Can anyone refer me to a datasheet/errata that speaks to the effect of setting the config bit?

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly answered in the datasheet.  The protection bits can be cleared, but only by a bulk erase.  So yes, you can reprogram the part, but you can never read out code-protected data.  It may be possible to read write-protected data (that is not code-protected), but in either case all the protection bits are cleared by a bulk erase.  After a bulk erase, the chip is back to factory-fresh state.

Comment: I don't know if you're completely right about your last statement.  I think __write__ protected data can be read but __read__ protected data cannot be read.

Comment: @Joel: Bad wording on my part.  Hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: What you describe is what I think should happen, but I don't see it anywhere in a datasheet.  I updated my question showing the sparse information in the datasheet.  I can't find it referenced anywhere else.  Can you update your answer with any datasheet/errata excerpt backing up your claims?

Comment: @Joel: OK, then it's in the programming spec.  I know I've read this many times, so it has to be in one of those.